# What does the inode column in netstat signify?

Tags: linux, networking, netstat

Issuing the command, `netstat -pulet`, there is an inode column that appears, and so issuing a `find` command I found that it links to inodes in the `/sys/kernel/slab/cgroup/<...>` section.

For instance, dnsmasq is

```
./sys/kernel/slab/ext4_inode_cache/cgroup/ext4_inode_cache(206:systemd-remount-fs.service)/slabs
```

I get that there is a unix as a file paradigm, but what can i do with identifying where this file is?